# nav>button - phrasing content where flow content is expected

Tags: html

As I've understood from spec, [button element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) can be used, where phrasing content is expected. And content model of [nav element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) is flow content. So why the following markup is valid?

```
<nav>
    <button class="prev"></button>
    <button class="next"></button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) includes phrasing content; the definition explicitly includes `button` element.

In HTML 4 (and even in HTML 2), the “strict” version requires that text-level content be wrapped in block-level containers, and “text-level” meant roughly the same as phrasing content. But there is no such requirement in HTML5.